# Why does my VBA code create an extra sheet when it runs?

Tags: vba, excel

My code works perfectly except it creates an extra sheet (whatever is next in the sequence...i.e "Sheet2".."Sheet3"...each time I run it. Could anyone help figure out why this is happening?...there should only be two Sheets Created as I have indicated in the code below:

```
Sub CopySheet()

Dim NewSheet As String
Dim PrevSheet As String
Dim CashWS As Worksheet
Dim MonthVal As String


NewSheet = InputBox("Which month is this Commissions statement for?")
PrevSheet = InputBox("What was the previous month?")

Worksheets(PrevSheet).Copy After:=Worksheets("Summary")
ActiveSheet.Name = NewSheet

Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=EOMONTH(DATE(2017,MONTH(DATEVALUE(MID(CELL(""filename"", RC[-5]), FIND(""]"", CELL(""filename"", RC[-5])) + 1, 255)&""1"")+1),1),0)"
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Range("D3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MONTH(R[-1]C)"
Range("D3").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
MonthVal = ActiveCell.Value


Set CashWS = Sheets.Add
Sheets.Add.Name = "2017_0" & MonthVal & " Cash"


End Sub
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below, it's worth mentioning that it's best to [avoid using `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).  It will help shorten/"tighten up" your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's happening in the final step:

```
Set CashWS = Sheets.Add
Sheets.Add.Name = "2017_0" & MonthVal & " Cash"
```

Change that to:

```
Set CashWS = Sheets.Add
CashWS.Name = "2017_0" & MonthVal & " Cash"
```

Doing the second `Sheet.Add.Name` adds a sheet *and* renames it at the same time.  When you do `Set CashWS = Sheets.Add`, Excel adds the sheet. So then, just use your WS Variable and update the name.

Edit: And for no real reason, I'll add that if you are partial to using `Sheets.Add.Name...` you could have done:

```
Sheets.Add.Name = "2017_0" & MonthVal & " Cash"
Set CashWS = ActiveSheet
```

then continued working with `CashWS` variable.

Comment: @Jeeped And you both beat my comment!

Comment: @Jeeped - I saw that, I got lucky this time!

Comment: @YowE3K thanks for your help as well!...setting it to just CashWS solves it!